# Can I convert Apk file back to android studio project?

Tags: android, apk, project

I made my android project and run the app on my phone. I got the apk file and also app but accidentally deleted app. Can anyone Help me out please.

Comment: What have you deleted? Your APK file or project or both?

Comment: just recompile the project again this will make the apk.

Answer (score 0):

If your apk not obfuscated by proguard or other third party also not build by signed. Probably you can use an software like [Dex2Jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar). But i am not really sure about this, you can try it. There are tutorial [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-decompile-an-android-app-apk)

Answer (score 0):

Reverse engineering your app is theoretically possible but hard.

1) Use the [Apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) which would help generate a little code and the resource files.

2) Use the [jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) tool which helps to produce Java source code from Android Dex and Apk files.

Next is to open a new Android Studio project, copy the manifest file generated by the [Apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) into the manifest of the new project, Copy the resource files generated by [Apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) to the `res` section of your new project, Copy the java files generated by [jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) and place them in the `src` folder of your new project.

Try to build the app but you'll definitely run into several errors. Try following the messages to fix them.

Reverse engineering your app is very tedious and you still might not be able to build the app.

Goodluck :)

*Added 24th November 2019*

Just found [this awesome article](http://w3bshark.com/blog/reverse-engineer) on how to go about Reverse Engineering an Apk.